# Django: Management Command Disappeared and I can't test the script

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I had a command all set up and working, then I set up a Cron job for it and now it disappeared from manage.py help's list of all available commands.

It is under 
/app/management/commands/feed_update.py

and it has a Command(BaseCommand) class with a handle() function.

The problem is that my script has dependencies to app.models so I can't even run the script to see if something is wrong and why manage.py won't pick it up automatically.

Is there a way to force manage.py to find the script?

Thanks.

Edit 1:
I just tried doing

```
manage.py shell

>> import app.management.commands.feed_update as fu
>> fu.Command.handle(fu.Command())
```

and everything worked fine. I just don't understand why it wont let me run it through manage.py

I have `__init__.py` files in every folder..

Edit 2:
The app is installed in Settings.py and is my main app that serves my web content so I am absolutely certain it is installed.

It can't find the command either in Cron or when I go in through the terminal (even though my other apps' Commands show up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be inside an application that is listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

If it seems to be there already, are you sure that the cron job is using the right settings.py?

Comment: Both the Cron Job and going manually through the terminal cannot find the command.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a problem almost identical to this except I'm using `django-admin.py`. A management command which worked perfectly on my dev machine wasn't appearing in the list of commands shown when you run `django-admin.py` without an argument. Turns out you need to run `django-admin.py` from within the root folder of your project if you want **custom** management commands to work.